# .gitignore The different between /foo and /foo/

Tags: git, gitignore

Are there any different between `foo/` and `/foo/` in `.gitignore`?
I've been reading in [git-doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) but I found nothing. Are those two the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There *is* a difference between `/foo` and `foo`.

To understand the difference, think about directories (or folders if you prefer that word) and the fact that they may contain nested sub-directories (sub-folders):

```
foo/a/file1
foo/b/file2
foo/file3
quux/foo/file4
```

Here, the *top level* directory `foo` contains two *sub-directories* `a` and `b` plus one file, and the sub-directories contain one file each.  The top-level directory `quux` contains a sub-directory `foo`, which contains one file.

#### If your `.gitignore` lists `foo`

If you tell Git to ignore `foo`, Git won't have to look inside `foo` to find `foo/a`, `foo/b`, and `foo/file3`.  Having not looked inside `foo`, Git won't look inside `foo/a` or `foo/b` either, and won't find either of `foo/a/file1` or `foo/b/file2`.

Meanwhile, nothing tells Git to skip `quux`, so Git will look inside `quux` and find `foo`.  If you tell Git to ignore `foo`, Git won't have to look inside `quux/foo`, so it won't find `quux/foo/file4`.

#### If your `.gitignore` lists `/foo` instead

However, if you have told Git to ignore `/foo` rather than `foo`, when Git finds `foo` inside `quux`, it *won't* match `/foo` because `/foo` means *only ignore `foo` at the top level*.  So Git *will* look inside `quux/foo` and hence *will* find `quux/foo/file4`.

#### Suffix slashes

As [Void Raider answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51664113/1256452), writing `foo/` in a `.gitignore` tells Git that it should match (and hence not look inside) the *directory* `foo`, but should *not* match (and hence will gripe about—see below) a plain *file* named `foo`.  Here, too, the leading slash remains significant: it tells Git whether to apply this to *all* things named `foo`, or only those things at the top level.

#### More detail, because the details matter

All of the above describes the action as if you have only one `.gitignore` file stored at the top level of your work-tree.  But you can store one `.gitignore` file *per directory*.  If you have a `quux` directory, you can create `quux/.gitignore`, for instance.  And, in the top level `.gitignore`, you could list a name like `quux/foo`, or you could list `foo` in `quux/.gitignore`.  What do each of these do?

First, let's define some terms:

- Unix-style path names are normally called either *absolute* if they start with `/`, such as `/a/b/c`, or *relative* if they do not, such as `a/b/c`.  An absolute path tells the operating system to start at the top of the host's directory tree, while a relative path tells the operating system to start at the *current directory*.
- Unix-style shells support what is called *globbing* or *glob* actions on path names.  Here, for instance, `*` matches any number (including zero) of any character, so that a name like `a*c` matches `ac`, abc`,`abbbc`,`axyzc`, and so on.
- Git supports (in multiple places, including in `.gitattributes` and as command line options) path name *patterns*, which Git calls *pathspecs*.  Different features in Git support different kinds of pathspecs.  Ignore files in particular implement glob patterns.

In a `.gitignore` file, any absolute path always refers to the *current directory*.  Hence, if `quux/.gitignore` exists, and contains `/foo`, that matches a file or directory named `quux/foo`.  You could put this into the top level `.gitignore` file as `/quux/foo`.

In any `.gitignore` file, any path name that contains an embedded `/` (not at the end of the pattern) is *also* treated as absolute!  This means that putting `quux/foo` into the top level `.gitignore` is *the same* as putting `/quux/foo` into the top level `.gitignore`!

Putting `foo` (with no leading slash) into `quux/.gitignore` means that Git would ignore `quux/sub/foo`, while putting `quux/foo` into the top-level `.gitignore` means that Git would *not* ignore `quux/sub/foo`, because of this peculiarity of treating embedded-slash pathnames as if they were absolute.

#### An important caveat: to be ignored, a path must not reside in the index

If a path name appears in your repository's *index*, no amount of fiddling with `.gitignore` files will make it ignored.

To see *everything* that is currently in the index, use `git ls-files --stage`.  Note that this prints a *lot* of names in a large repository!  This is why you normally don't ever look at the index directly: it's just too much, like trying to look at the sun.  It's much better to *compare* what's in the index to something else.  That's what `git status` does, and that's where `.gitignore` files really enter the picture.

When you run `git status`, Git runs *two* comparisons.  The first one compares the current, or `HEAD`, commit to the index.  Whatever is *different* here, `git status` calls this *staged for commit*.  This is because `git commit` will use whatever is in the index right now to make the new snapshot.  We're usually concerned not with *every* file that will be in the snapshot, but rather with those files that will be *different* in the new snapshot, as compared to the current snapshot.  So that's what `git status` shows us: files that are different, or *staged for commit*.

The *second* comparison compares what's in the index to what is in your work-tree.  Whatever is different here, `git status` calls this *not staged for commit* or—for some files—*untracked*.  Some of these *untracked files* will be files that you do not *want* to commit, and you do not want Git bothering you about them.

An *untracked file* is quite simply defined as *a path name that is not in the index at all*.  If that same path name exists in the work-tree, the file is untracked.  Git will whine about it.  Listing that path name in a `.gitignore` file will tell Git: *Shut up about this file, it's **supposed to be** untracked.*  But if it's *tracked*—if the file is already in the index—Git won't check `.gitignore` for its name; it will just assume that the file *should* be committed.

Comment: Very useful point about the fact that if a file already in the index, then git won't check .gitignore. That explained why git was allowing me to commit some files which should have been ignored according to .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `/foo` find a match with a file or a directory, `/foo/` only matches a directory, while `/foo/*` matches directories and files inside foo. Hope this helps!

EDIT: Also `/foo` and `/foo/` are the same.

Comment: `/foo` and `/foo/` are **NOT** the same! The former ignores any file or directory, the latter only directory. Also you've forgotten to mention difference between `foo/` and `/foo/` — the difference is that `foo/` matches in any subdirectory while `/foo/` matches only in the same directory where the `.gitignore` resides.